# Ubuntu Live CD is Frozen - How to Recover?

Tags: data-recovery, live-cd, live-environment

I'm in a tricky situation. I'm running Ubuntu from a live cd. I think I have too many firefox pages and tabs open, so the computer is frozen. However, I have some unsaved, and very important, text editor files open. At first the computer wouldn't respond at all, after a few hours, the screen woke up and now it's just a black screen with the unmoving mouse cursor. **Any way to recover without restarting?** Maybe somehow kill the firefox processes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. **These files are massively important**. Losing then would be a huge loss.

Comment: Do you have a terminal prompt? Do you get one after pressing enter? What about after pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1? If you can get to a terminal prompt you might be able to kill processes and get the GUI to respond again. If you can't get to a terminal there's really no hope. Running from Live Media is generally designed not to leave any traces on the host system. Moreover, you really shouldn't run demanding programs from Live Media, as you likely don't have an swap space.

Comment: Cross posted to superuser.com twice: http://superuser.com/questions/795566/ubuntu-live-cd-is-frozen-how-to-recover and http://superuser.com/questions/795629/computer-is-frozen-is-there-any-way-to-save-the-contents-of-ram

Comment: The keyboard shortcut isn't working. However, I can still hear the cd whirring. Does that mean I can wait this out?